# Why is Android WiFi Direct and Network Discovery so unreliable?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am investigating Android Wifi Direct and Network Discovery.

I have followed the Google Android examples and come to the same conclusion on both implementations.

They are completely and utterly Unreliable.

I have followed this training tutorial
https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

WiFi Direct issues.

My call to

```
 mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener()
```

ALWAYS returns success

however my Broadcast receiver either doesn't receive

```
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION
```

at all

or when it does receive `WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` the peer list is alway empty (e.g size() = 0).

I have four Android devices available to be "discovered"

and very rarely some of them are discovered.

The link I have shared seems pretty basic and simple to follow. I have passed listeners to all possible method calls and have never seen I fail error log.

What is the secret to developing a reliable WiFiDirect Android application.

The code I have developed matches EXACTLY that documented in the above link.

What debugging tools can I use to identify what my issue(s) are/is?

Comment: try this tutorial https://androcraftsite.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/wifi-direct/

Comment: @sahil This tutorial is a slight improvement. As my Nexus 7 can "see" the my google Pixel. However the Pixel does not detect the Nexus and neither the Nexus or Pixel can detect my Samsung Tablet.

Comment: ok maybe thw problem is the MAC address you get using Manager is not same ...try this one ...it works jist fine and all your issue will be solved. https://github.com/ahmontero/wifi-direct-demo

Comment: @Sahil, thanks for your time on this, sadly that latest app gives exactly the same results as the previous one. Only my Nexus 7 detects the Pixel and no other devices can be discovered

Comment: oh ...i'll get into this soon right now on mobile. Will try it on my samsung and will post the code soon enough for you. cheers

Comment: also what are the android versions you got in your phones. before 4.0 you need to swicth off regular wifi and after 4.0 you need to have regular wifi enabled.

Comment: Nexus 7 - Android 6.0.1, Samsung Tablet - Android 4.4.1, Pixel - Android 8.0.0

Comment: i'll give it a try and will post the code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153601/discussion-between-hector-and-sahil).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @CodeWiget, No, I believe its impossible to use WiFi on an android device to develop any sort of P2P network application. The available API's are just not fit for purpose